# Active Directory Management Tools Installation

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I would like to install on new Windows Server 2008 the same Active Directory management browser as we had on old server Win2000, but i am not able to find out the feature/role. 
This server is not domain controller, the AD is just connected to DC.

Is it any part of administration tools which are not installed on server?

Comment: Do you just mean the active directory users and computers MMC snapin?

Comment: probably yes, so its MMC snapin installer? thats what i am looking for? mine problem is that i am completely out of experience, so without knowledge of these terms its hard to know what exactly you are looking for ..

Comment: Are you going with 2008 or 2008 R2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, what you're looking for are the "Remote Server Administration Tools," often abbreviated RSAT. You can install them on servers or workstations. There are different versions of RSAT for different versions of Windows.

After you've installed them, you will still need to go into Programs and Features and enable them.

In fact they may already be there on your server... go to `Programs and Features` -> `Turn Windows features on or off` and look for `Remote Server Administration Tools` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need GPMC for group policies and that is also a feature you need to enable.